Postman App not able to copy cookies when trying to mouse hover

In postman app, when I login and the access token is set. I may want to copy those values for the header authorization but however do not know why when I use the mouse hover it then the mouse cursor became disabled t. May I ask what is the way to copy the values?

You should select Cookies tab at the bottom and there is a possibility to select a particular cookie and copy its value.
